# How to list all apps to get appID on app engine in google cloud platform using python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-client

I'm trying to write a simple python code to list out the apps such that i will get all the appIDs in google-cloud-platform , In command prompt i'm able to list it by passing the below command

```
gcloud app instances list
```

When i searched in stack overflow and other websites i couldn't find any piece of code that can list me apps. Any information related this will be thankful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can run it in cmd, you could simply run the command from within Python:

```
import os
os.system("gcloud app instances list")
```

There is also the [official google cloud python package](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/), but it might be overkill if all you want to do is to run that one command.

Comment: this is kind of hack to get the list of instance and i dont want that i wanted to know which service from googleapiclient python library will help me retrive me the list thanks